# What is the distribution for the maximum (minimum) of two independent normal random variables?

Tags: normal-distribution, extreme-value

Specifically, suppose $X$ and $Y$ are normal random variables (independent but not necessarily identically distributed).  Given any particular $a$, is there a nice formula for $P(\max(X,Y)\leq x)$ or similar concepts?  Do we know that $\max(X,Y)$ is normally distributed, maybe a formula for mean and standard deviation in terms of those for $X$ and $Y$?  I checked the usual places (wikipedia, google) but didn't find anything.

Comment: Related: [Distribution of the maximum of two correlated normal variables](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/139072/17230), [Asymptotic distribution of maximum order statistic of IID random normals](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/34418/17230), & [Is there an analytical expression for the distribution of the max of a normal k sample?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3309/17230)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The max of two non-identical Normals can be expressed as an Azzalini skew-Normal distribution. See, for instance, a 2007 working paper/presentation by  [Balakrishnan](http://www-1.ms.ut.ee/tartu07/presentations/balakrishnan.pdf)

> A Skewed Look at Bivariate and Multivariate Order Statistics
> Prof. N. Balakrishnan
> Working paper / presentation (2007)

A recent paper by ([Nadarajah and Kotz - viewable here](https://www.gwern.net/docs/conscientiousness/2008-nadarajah.pdf)) gives some properties of max$(X,Y)$:

> Nadarajah, S. and Kotz, S. (2008), "Exact Distribution of the Max/Min of Two Gaussian Random Variables", IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON VERY LARGE SCALE INTEGRATION (VLSI) SYSTEMS, VOL. 16, NO. 2, FEBRUARY 2008

For earlier work, see:

> A. P. Basu and J. K. Ghosh, “Identifiability of the multinormal and other distributions under competing risks model,” J. Multivariate Anal., vol. 8, pp. 413–429, 1978
>
> H. N. Nagaraja and N. R. Mohan, “On the independence of system life distribution and cause of failure,” Scandinavian Actuarial J., pp. 188–198, 1982.
>
> Y. L. Tong, The Multivariate Normal Distribution. New York: Springer-Verlag, 1990.

---

One can also use a computer algebra system to automate the calculation. For example, given $X \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ with pdf $f(x)$, and $Y \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ with pdf $g(y)$:

[image]

... the pdf of $Z = max(X,Y)$ is:

[image]

where I am using the `Maximum` function from the *mathStatica* package of *Mathematica*, and `Erf` denotes the error function.

Comment: Since I don't have access to this paper, care to share the formula they derive?

Comment: I have added some further references ... and provided an automated CAS derivation

Comment: @RichardRast I've found a live reference to Nadarajah and Kotz - added above for your viewing pleasure

Comment: Be careful with this publication. I think there are quite a few sign errors in there (like $x + \mu_1$ instead of $x - \mu_1$).

Answer (score 9):

I'm surprised that in the previous answers the most interesting property is not mentioned: the cumulative-probability distribution for the maximum is the product of the respective cumulative-probability distributions.

Comment: That's interesting. Is that just for normals, or any distributions? Do you have a citation I can look to read more about this?

Comment: @RichardRast, it's true for any type of randomly distributed independent variables see this post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145659/order-statistics-of-independent-not-identically-distributed-random-variables/314089?noredirect=1#comment783583_314089

Comment: Should be easy to prove: $P(\max(X,Y)\leq x) = P(X\leq x \wedge Y\leq x) = P(X\leq x)P(Y\leq x) = F_X(x) F_Y(x)$, where the second equality stems from the independence of $X$ and $Y$. The density is then $(F_X(x) F_Y(x))'=F_X(x) f_Y(x) + f_X(x) F_Y(x)$, which would give for Gaussians $X$ and $Y$: $f((x-\mu_1)/\sigma_1)\Phi((x-\mu_2)/\sigma_2) + f((x-\mu_2)/\sigma_2)\Phi((x-\mu_1)/\sigma_1)$, where $f$ is the density and $\Phi$ the cdf of a standard Gaussian.