# If you take the maximum value from two random draws from a normal distribution, what is the mean and standard deviation of the resulting distribution?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, order-statistics

Let's say I draw two numbers from a normal distribution with mean 50 and sd 10, and take the maximum of those two numbers. If I generate a distribution of that maximum, what are the resulting characteristics of the distribution, and what is the intuition behind this calculation?

One idea is that the mean should be at the 75th percentile of the original distribution, which would be about 56.7. This is because if you take the largest of N independent draws, in expectation it should come from the middle (mass-wise) highest Nth (mass-wise) of the distribution (based on taking the max of say 1000 draws instead of 2 draws).

However, this doesn't appear correct according to simulation:

For example:

```
a<- rnorm(mean = 50, sd = 10, n= 100000)
b<- rnorm(mean = 50, sd = 10, n= 100000)
max_dist = pmax(a,b)
mean(max_dist)
sd(max_dist)

> mean(max_dist)
[1] 55.645
> sd(max_dist)
[1] 8.2525
```

What is the analytical solution to generating this mean and standard deviation? In particular, is there a general solution for knowing the mean and standard deviation if the random normals have different means and standard deviations?

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173064/what-is-the-distribution-for-the-maximum-minimum-of-two-independent-normal-ran

Comment: `mean(qnorm(qbeta(ppoints(10^6),2,1),50,10))` in R suggests a mean of the maximum of $55.6419$ so your simulation is close

Comment: The density is discussed at Henry's link, but if $X_{(2)}=\max(X_1,X_2)$, note that $P(X_{(2)}≤t)$ $=$ $P(X_1≤t,X_2≤t)$ $=$ $F_1(t).F_2(t)$, and the density can be obtained by differentiation. Similar arguments can be produced for the minimum.

Comment: Any chance you can explain what any of that is doing, @Henry? I'm already lost with your `ppoints` call

Comment: `ppoints(10^6)` are a million equally spaced points in $[0,1]$.  So `qbeta(ppoints(10^6),2,1)` are in a handwaving sense a million equally likely points in a Beta distribution for the maximum of two iid uniform random variables.  And `qnorm(qbeta(ppoints(10^6),2,1),50,10)` are a million equally likely points in the distribution for the maximum of two iid normal random variables.  So we can take the mean of those and be close to the overall mean